# How to convert a string to x-www-form-urlencoded in Java?

Tags: java

I have a string

```
"To=\"+911234567899\"&From=\"+9987654321\"&Body=\"Hen\""
```

which I need to convert into x-www-form-urlencoded format.

If I use `URLEncoder.encode()` in Java, the function is converting the string as

```
To%3D%22%2B911234567899%22%26From%3D%22%2B9987654321%22%26Body%3D%22Hen%22
```

but when I send the request from postman as x-www-form-urlencoded the request that gets send is

```
To=%22%2B911234567899%22&From=%22%2B9987654321%22&Body=%22Hen%22
```

Why this difference? Also I need to send the request as it's exactly the same in postman (the second encoded string) then only I'm getting the response back. How can I encode my string in second format?

Comment: the problem you are facing is double encoding

Comment: Since you get double-encoded, what's the problem if you don't encode with `URLEncoder.encode()`? It should be encoded only once automatically and should work, right?

Comment: Thanks for your replies, actually I'm sending the request from my Tool which doesn't do the encoding while sending the request, hence I need to manually do it. But when I'm using URL.encode() on the above string it is not encoding it in format which being send by postman.

Comment: Can we have a regex for this?

Answer (score 1):

You probably double encoded your strings. Perhaps you shouldn't encode your query string yourself, and let URLEncoder do the work for you.

Here is an example, assume I have keys and values in a hashmap `this.params`.

```
this.params.put(key, URLEncoder.encode(value.toString(), "UTF-8")); // set the key/value

StringBuilder param = new StringBuilder("");
for (Map.Entry<String, Object> item : this.params.entrySet()) {
    if (param.toString().length() != 0) {
        param.append('&');
    }
    param.append(item.getKey());
    param.append('=');
    param.append(item.getValue().toString());
}
```

Now `param.toString()` will be properly encoded. Use it with `url + "?" + param.toString()`

Comment: `StringBuilder.append` returns `StringBuilder` object again so can use successive calls to `append` method  in the same statement like `param.append("appendMe").append("andMe").append("meAsWell").toString(); `